# How to simply play a CMSampleBufferRef audio data?

Tags: ios, audio, avcapturesession, openal, objectal

I'm capturing audio within an `AVCaptureSession`, now I'm about to play it.

I'm really not into lower level audio processing, so [**`ObjectAL`**](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone) seems a fair choice for this, so I tried to get buffer pointer, some format information, then create an ObjectAL buffer.

```
 -(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput*) captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection*) connection
{
    if ([captureOutput isKindOfClass:[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput class]])
    {

        // Get samples.
        CMBlockBufferRef audioBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
        size_t lengthAtOffset;
        size_t totalLength;
        char *samples;
        CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer(audioBuffer, 0, &lengthAtOffset, &totalLength, &samples);

        // Get format.
        CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef format = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);
        const AudioStreamBasicDescription *description = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(format);

        ALBuffer *openALbuffer = [ALBuffer bufferWithName:@"buffer just captured before"
                                                     data:sampleBuffer
                                                     size:totalLength
                                                   format:description->mFormatID
                                                frequency:description->mSampleRate];
    }
}
```

It says `Invalid Value`:

```
OAL Error: +[ALWrapper bufferDataStatic:format:data:size:frequency:]: Invalid Value (error code 0x0000a003)
```

ObjectAL actually hooks to some OpenAL stuff I did not get into, you may understand it better:**[`ALBuffer.m`](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALBuffer.m)**, [**`ALWrapper.m`**](https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/OpenAL/ALWrapper.m#L1413)

### **Is there any format / buffer conversation** I have to utilize before create such ObjectAL (OpenAL) buffer?

Comment: What data is being passed into bufferWithName (size, format, frequency)? OpenAL requires uncompressed little endian signed 16-bit PCM data.

Comment: Some example code to print an ASBD is at the bottom of this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html

Comment: Thanks for getting back, it uses `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` default. Will try to override with the above.

Comment: Just can't use audioSettings. :( Here I can see, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnitOSX/Listings/CaptureSessionController_mm.html, but this property seems to be unavailable as of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html (Ahh, it is an OSX feature)

Comment: You just need to print out the AudioStreamBasicDescription you got from CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription so that you can see what kind of audio data you have. My first guess is that the format of the captured audio data is something OpenAL doesn't understand.

Comment: I'm fine with this, but have no idea how to **set** audio capture format actually, as there is no hook for that. Gonna capture audio separately then (where I can set format manually), but sync with video looks to be more painful then.

Comment: It goes like: https://gist.github.com/eppz/11254372

Comment: Then I create like: https://gist.github.com/eppz/11254457

Comment: So it outputs like: https://gist.github.com/eppz/11254491

Comment: Do you have any suggestion I can try here? Or I have to play with... ...some Audio Unit I really wanted to spare. :(

Comment: I can't really debug something like `Invalid Value`... :/

Comment: Implemented painfully with `AudioToolbox`. :(